# VRP minimize total distance

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a vrp with capacity constraints (python). What i have to do is to minimize the total distance of the routes using the method addVariableMinimizedFinalizer(), but i don't understand how to use it. If I understand well, the parameter that I have to put in the method is the variable that I have to minimize in the objective function. However I don't understand how to write this code and where to insert it in my code. Here the code that I used to insert the distance dimension:

dimension_name = 'Distance'

```
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,
    3000,
    True,
    dimension_name)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
```